# visual studio code .net core test explorer debugger

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-code, nunit-3.0, test-explorer

I installed nunit Version 3.12.0 NUnit3TestAdapter Version 3.15.1, Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk Version 16.4.0 and the .net core test explorer. I can run tests from my test explorer and they will succeed and fail accordingly, howeever when I select a test from my test explorer and click on debug test i get the following output

```
Test run for onis.test.Tests.Test1, expecting 1 test results file(s) in total
Executing dotnet build in d:/downloads/miscellaneous/workspace/Onis.test
Executing dotnet test --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=C:\Users\Timmeh\AppData\Local\Temp\test-explorer-pIbP9n\0.trx" --filter "FullyQualifiedName=onis.test.Tests.Test1" in d:/downloads/miscellaneous/workspace/Onis.test
Process 14440 started
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
Waiting for debugger to attach
New test results file
Parsed 1/1 file(s)
Parsed all expected test results, updating tree
Debugger finished
Process 14440 finished
```

The test takes forever to finish and it never stops at my breakpoint. How do I debug my C# unit tests in Visual Studio Code

Comment: Ping the extension authors, https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-dotnet-test-explorer/issues